Reaching perfect squares by applying either $n \rightarrow n+1$ or $n \rightarrow 2n+1$
Recently, I think of a game. You are given some positive integer starting value. Then you are given a choice of whether to apply $n \rightarrow n+1$ and $n \rightarrow 2n +1$. Your goal, as a player, is to reach a perfect square in as few steps as possible.
Let $a(k)$ be the smallest starting value where with optimal play, you can win in $k$ moves exactly. So for example, $a(20) = 8894$. Here is a sequence starting $8894$ that wins in $20$ moves:
$$8894, 8895, 17791, 17792, 35585, 71171, 142343, 284687, 569375, 569376, 1138753, 1138754, 2277509, 2277510, 4555021, 4555022, 9110045, 18220091, 36440183, 36440184, 72880369 = 8537^2$$
Here is the value of $a(k)$ for $0≤k≤23$:
$$1,3,2,5,18,26,42,50,72,182,211,210,496,743,946,1314,2984,2983,5644,7579,8894,15719,22764,33443$$
(Interestingly, $2983 = a(17) < a(16) = 2984$)
Can anyone provide some approximation to $a(k)$? Is there some faster way to find an optimal path without having to bruteforce your way into finding one?

How do you win in one move, starting from $n=2$? Neither $n+1=3$ nor $2n+1=5$ is a square.

k=2 should be a(k)=3

I got things switched up

Perhaps something for OEIS. I wonder whether the determination of $a_n$ is NP-complete.

@BryleMorga What is the smalles number for which we need more than $23$ moves to win ?

@Peter Well, it is $47701$ which is $a(24)$ . The sequence continues with $a(25) = 82189$ and i'm still calculating $a(26)$

Faster-than-brute-force algorithm
For the starting value of $n=8894$, let's assume that you know you'll apply $n \rightarrow 2n+1$ exactly 13 times.
Applying $n \rightarrow 2n+1$ 13 times is equivalent to $n \rightarrow 2^{13}(n+1) - 1$, in our case $8894 \rightarrow 72867839$.
We can add some $n \rightarrow n+1$ steps in. Each such step will increment the total by one of $\{2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ..., 2^{13}\}$ depending on how many
$n \rightarrow 2n+1$ steps follow it.
The next square number after $72867839$ is $8537^2$. The "deficit" to reach this square number is $12530$, which requires $7$ powers of $2$. (Note that $12530 = 11000011110010_2$ which has $7$ $1$'s). So, we can reach $8537^2$ in $13+7=20$ steps.
We also need to consider reaching $8538^2$ and larger squares instead of $8537^2$.
Though, once we consider $8540^2$, we see that adding $2^{13}$ $7$ times isn't enough to reach $8540^2$, so $8540^2$ and larger squares aren't worth considering.
This proves that 20 steps is optimal for a starting value of $8894$, assuming we apply $n \rightarrow 2n+1$ exactly 13 times.
Generalizing this technique gives a fast algorithm that quickly finds $a(1..38)$. Larger results are unreliable with my code because of 64-bit-signed integer overflow.
Note: a(1),a(2) and a(10),a(11), and a(16),a(17) are printed "out of order"
a(0) = 1
a(2) = 2
a(1) = 3
a(3) = 5
a(4) = 18
a(5) = 26
a(6) = 42
a(7) = 50
a(8) = 72
a(9) = 182
a(11) = 210
a(10) = 211
a(12) = 496
a(13) = 743
a(14) = 946
a(15) = 1314
a(17) = 2983
a(16) = 2984
a(18) = 5644
a(19) = 7579
a(20) = 8894
a(21) = 15719
a(22) = 22764
a(23) = 33443
a(24) = 47701
a(25) = 82189
a(26) = 150992
a(27) = 211168
a(28) = 303140
a(29) = 485004
a(30) = 705876
a(31) = 1109631
a(32) = 1517419
a(33) = 2263061
a(34) = 3633386
a(35) = 5643408
a(36) = 8298945
a(37) = 9462424
a(38) = 18499222

int64_t powerOf2( int64_t k ) // returns 2^k
{
   return 1LL << k;
}

int calcNumSteps( int64_t n )
{
   int bestNumSteps = 9999;

   for ( int numberOfDoublings = 0; numberOfDoublings <= bestNumSteps; numberOfDoublings++ )
   {
      int64_t a = (n + 1) * powerOf2( numberOfDoublings ) - 1; // `a` is the result of applying "n -> 2n+1" `numberOfDoublings` times
      if ( a < 0 )
      {
         trace << "overflow while calculating calcNumSteps with n=" << n << endl;
         exit( 0 );
      }

      int64_t r = (int64_t)floor( sqrt( a ) );                 // r = under-estimated square-root of `a`
      for ( r; ; r++ )
      {
         int64_t targetSquareNumber = r * r;
         int64_t deficit = targetSquareNumber - a;
         if ( deficit < 0 )
            continue;

         int64_t incrementSize = powerOf2( numberOfDoublings ); // inserting "n -> n+1" into our sequence will increase the final value
                                                                // by 2^k, where k is the number of subsequence "n -> 2n+1" operations
         if ( deficit > incrementSize * (bestNumSteps - numberOfDoublings) )
            break; // can't possibly cover a deficit this big in less than `bestNumSteps` steps

         int numSteps = numberOfDoublings;

         int numTimesToApplyIncrement = deficit / incrementSize;
         deficit -= numTimesToApplyIncrement * incrementSize;
         numSteps += numTimesToApplyIncrement;
         numSteps += std::popcount( (uint64_t) deficit );

         bestNumSteps = min( numSteps, bestNumSteps );
      }
   }

   return bestNumSteps;
}

void main()
{
   vector<bool> used( 1000 );

   for ( int n = 1; n <= 1'000'000'000; n++ )
   {
      int numSteps = calcNumSteps( n );
      if ( used[numSteps] )
         continue;
      used[numSteps] = true;
      cout << "a(" << numSteps << ")" << " = " << n << endl;
   }
}

